# React router not rendering as expected on the server

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to get react rendering on a php server using [php-V8Js](http://php.net/manual/en/book.v8js.php).

Single components render fine but I'm having trouble rendering children using `<RouterContext />`.

```
<?php
    $v8js = new V8Js();
    ob_start();
    $v8js->executeString(file_get_contents(PUBLIC_PATH . '/js/bundle.js'), 'v8.js');
    $content = ob_get_clean();
    echo $content;
```

App.jsx (bundle.js)

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Router, Route, Link, browserHistory, IndexRoute, match, RouterContext } from 'react-router'

import Master from './views/Master.jsx';
import About from './views/About.jsx';

var routes = {
    path: '/',
    component: 'Master',
    indexRoute: {
        component: 'About'
    }
}

if (typeof document === 'undefined'){
    match({
            routes,
            location: '/'
        },
        function(error, redirectLocation, renderProps) {
            print( React.renderToString(<RouterContext {...renderProps}/>));
    })
}
```

The source html this sends to the client is:

```
<Master data-reactid=".1dpk2jzhts0" data-react-checksum="2085756513">
  <About data-reactid=".1dpk2jzhts0.0"></About>
</Master>
```

It's not including any of either components HTML.

If I swap out `<RouterContext/>` for `<About />` or `<Master />` the html for either is rendered, but when using RouterContext it only renders the root tag of each component.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is it because you're passing component's as strings e.g. `'Master'` rather than the imported component `Master`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is because you are passing `'Master'` and `'About'` as strings, so React just creates new empty elements. You need to use your `Master` and `About` as variables that you imported above:

`var routes = {
    path: '/',
    component: Master,
    indexRoute: {
        component: About
    }
}`

Upboats to Brad, I think going with Nodejs would be the best route too, it should be better supported and uses V8 anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I avoided php-V8Js like the plague. Instead, I followed Airbnb's example [The Evolution of Airbnb’s Frontend](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gMvvb6F8dgk). Basically, just install Node on your server and use something like [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/) to do an HTTP request to the local Node server. Send your PHP data over a POST request to localhost:3000 or whatever. Then all you have to do is follow the [React Router docs](http://%20Passwordhttps://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ServerRendering.md) to set up server-side rendering.

I talk a little about how I handled this issue [here](https://medium.com/@bradestey/redesigning-bimmershops-649dff2e0aa).

Comment: Pete's answer solved the issue I was having but after the pain I had setting up php v8js locally I think I'll go with your node js suggestion when moving to live, thanks for the tip.